# How do I prevent Apple Watch from silencing my phone's vibration on notifications?

Tags: iphone, notifications, apple-watch

I've got an Apple Watch, and because haptic feedback is physically disturbing me, I've turned it off. However, I'm getting all notifications on the watch but my phone is not vibrating on a notification, but I **do** want it to vibrate.

How do I get my phone notifications back?

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. The notifications will be displayed in one or another, but never in both devices.

If you want notifications back in your phone, you have to turn it off in your watch.

Comment: There is nothing that I don't want to see on my watch. Did you read the question?

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu when too fast. I updated my answer.

Comment: Really? I think I'll return it then.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu this is generally true of some other smart watches too - I have the Pebble watch and whenever my phone is connected and detects its on a table or something, the phone doesn't buzz.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this issue isn't operator error. I sincerely hope the folks at Apple can design a way for both devices to receive alerts. I missed a text from my husband because I was bundled up with gloves and a heavy coat, and was moving around so I couldn't hear it and did not feel it. We need both!... for a variety of different reasons. Please, please, please develop this option.

Answer (score 0):

The Watch is designed to handle all the notifications on the phone, without the phone having to give any alerts. The only exception to this would be for phone calls, when the iPhone either rings or vibrates, as well as the Watch. The only way for you to get your phone to vibrate on some notifications is to customize the notification settings on the Watch to only show the notifications you want on the Watch--e.g., Messages, Mail, and Calendar--while turning off all other notifications. If you do this, a notification from Twitter will vibrate the phone, but not the Watch.

Comment: This doesn't cover my use case, sorry.